# "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" Not working in OSX Lion .bash_profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, rvm

Using [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" in .bash_profile.

OSX Lion

In order to launch rails server or bundle install in a project folder, I have to enter
     $rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd

each time I create a new terminal window, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd all the time, you should create .rvmrc in working project.
just echo "rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd" > .rvmrc in your terminal.